# How do I center an image in the README.md file on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown

I've been looking at the Markdown syntax used in GitHub for a while, but except resizing an image to the width of the `README.md` page, I can't figure out how to center an image in it.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/168) has proposed a general syntax for describing textual content that, should it become part of the Markdown standard, would facilitate centering images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

> I've been looking at the Markdown syntax used in GitHub [...], I can't figure out how to center an image

**TL;DR**

No, you can't by **only** relying on Markdown syntax. Markdown doesn't care about positioning.

*Note:* Some Markdown processors support inclusion of HTML (as rightfully pointed out by @waldyr.ar), and in the GitHub case you may fallback to something like `<div style="text-align:center"><img src="..." /></div>`.

Beware that there's no guarantee the image will be centered if your repository is forked in a different hosting environment ([CodePlex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex), [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket), etc.) or if the document isn't read through a browser ([Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) Markdown preview, MarkdownPad, Visual Studio Web Essentials Markdown preview, ...).

*Note 2:* Keep in mind that even within the GitHub website, the way Markdown is rendered is not uniform. The wiki, for instance, won't allow such CSS positional trickery.

**Unabridged version**

The **[Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)** doesn't provide one with the ability to control the position of an image.

In fact, it would be borderline against the Markdown philosophy to allow such formatting, as stated in the **"[Philosophy](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#philosophy)"** section.

> "A Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions. "

Markdown files are rendered by github.com website through the use of the Ruby **[Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)** library.

Redcarpet exposes some **[extensions](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-its-like-really-simple-to-use)** (such as strikethrough, for instance) which are not part of standard Markdown syntax and provide additional "features". However, no supported extension allow you to center an image.

Comment: This works just fine: `<img align="..." src="..." alt="...">`

Comment: @JohonnyPauling, if you are worried about not using too much github bandwith, you can give a look to [Raw Git](https://rawgit.com/), that serves files stored on GitHub, caching them on their system. So, just one access is performed on the resource on GitHub, saving their bandwith.

Comment: Original markdown processes markdown syntax within span tags. So some thing like the following should work:

`<span style="display:block;text-align:center">![Test Automation]Automated-Testing.png)</span>`

Comment: The `align` attribute on an `img` tag is deprecated as of HTML 4.01 and obsolete as of HTML5.

Comment: @Nux What is fine about it? `align` doesn't take `center` value.

Comment: @x-yuri It kind of does... You can test with `<p align="center">` and it will work... But I guess it's not working for images in FF... I think it might have worked in Opera (which I used back in 2013 ;-)). The `align` attribute is deprecated now anyway... So YMMV. One of the reasons for depreciation was that the implementations were too different.

Comment: One shall also mind if you are using a relative path to the image that the HTML code does not work the same as the markdown: it is relative to the root URL and not the current page.

Comment: @Nux No it does not, at least on Google Colab.

Answer (score 873):

This is from GitHub's support:

> Markdown doesn't allow you to tweak alignment directly (see docs here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img), but you can just use a raw HTML 'img' tag and do the alignment with inline css.

So **it is possible to align images!** You just have to use inline CSS to solve the problem. You can take an example from my [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/waldyr/Sublime-Installer/blob/master/README.md). At the bottom of README.md there is a centered aligned image. For simplicity you can just do as follows:

```html
<p align="center">
  <img src="http://some_place.com/image.png" />
</p>
```

Although, as [nulltoken said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/how-do-i-center-an-image-in-the-readme-md-file-on-github/12091563#12091563), it would be borderline against the Markdown philosophy!

---

This code from [my README file](https://github.com/waldyr/Sublime-Installer/blob/master/README.md):

```html
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://github.com/waldyr/Sublime-Installer/blob/master/sublime_text.png?raw=true" alt="Sublime's custom image"/>
</p>
```

It produces this image output, except centered when viewed on GitHub:

```html
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://github.com/waldyr/Sublime-Installer/blob/master/sublime_text.png?raw=true" alt="Sublime's custom image"/>
</p>
```

Comment: This appears to work (as seen in the poster's repo), but CSS is NOT supported in the Github wiki. Every attempt I've made to specify CSS has been stripped out. Likewise, the _align_ attribute specified is also removed when I attempt do do this in the wiki.

Comment: didn't worked to me in GitHub. `<p align="center"><img src="image" /></p>` nor  `<p style="align:center"><img src="image" /></p>` nor with `a` tag, etc.

Comment: alt for the image doesn't work, otherwise it is fine :)

Comment: @logoff You have errors in your css (should be `text-align:center`) and css is not supported.

Comment: It seems that the `align` attribute is [not supported in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_p_align.asp)?

Comment: They lied to you! I have tried using CSS via `class` and `style` attributes and it is not working at all! And YES, `align` was deprecated somewhere around HTML 4 and XHTML standards...

Comment: There is no CSS in the answer or in the markdown at the given link--`align` is a plain HTML property. CSS would be referenced by a `class` property or used in a `style` property.

Comment: For **GitLab**, you have to use `div`, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273660/how-do-you-center-text-in-gitlab-markdown) post: 
```<div align="center">
  <img />
</div>```

Comment: Any way align multiple images in center?

Comment: It looks like this solution is deprecated (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html), so I don't think we should be using it anymore. All the examples like it in this link say "deprecated" next to them.

Comment: I just did a ton of research and wrote this big answer with tons of info and explanations. Here's the proper way to do it today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383408/4561887.

Comment: I just want to point out that although this solution does indeed work, it is causing a lot of confusion to claim to use `inline css to solve the problem`, since, like @Poikilos points out, this answer has no CSS in it whatsoever. Rather, the `align="center"` part of the `<p>` element is a [deprecated HTML attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) (that happens to still function) & is NOT CSS. All CSS, whether [external, internal, or inline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) is banned from GitHub readmes & explicitly removed. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: Done: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383408/4561887) is updated and proven to work on Github in readmes now. I have lots of examples: image resizing, aligning left, center, and right both with and withOUT word wrap, having multiple images in a single row, etc.

Comment: Relative paths for images from same Github repo will also work.

 <img src="../../assets/user/my-image.png">

Answer (score 75):

This answer covers the topic: *Centering, sizing, and aligning images in markdown.*

**TLDR:**
Just jump straight down to look at the 4 examples (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4) in the section below called **"1. Centering and aligning images *in GitHub readmes* using the deprecated HTML `align` attribute"**!

Also, view actual examples of this on GitHub in a couple readme markdown files in my repositories here:

1. https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md
2. and https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world#3-markdown

   1. [image]

## Background on how to center and align images in markdown:

So, it turns out that **GitHub explicitly blocks/filters out *all attempts at editing any form of CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) styles (including [external, internal, and inline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp))* inside GitHub `*.md` markdown files, such as readmes.** See here (emphasis added):

1. [Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo/51956450#51956450)

   > GitHub does not allow for **CSS** to affect README.md files through **CSS** for security reasons...
2. https://github.community/t/github-flavored-markdown-doesnt-render-css-styles-inside-a-html-block/126258/2?u=electricrcaircraftguy

   > Unfortunately you cannot use **CSS** in GitHub markdown as it is a part of the sanitization process.
   >
   > > The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, **inline-styles**, and `class` or `id` attributes.
   >
   > source: https://github.com/github/markup

**So, that means to center or align images *in GitHub readmes*, your only solution is to use the [deprecated HTML `align` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) (that happens to still function), as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118349/4561887) shows.**

I should also point out that although that solution does indeed work, it is causing a lot of confusion for that answer to claim to use `inline css to solve the problem`, since, like @Poikilos points out in the comments, that answer has no CSS in it whatsoever. Rather, the `align="center"` part of the `<p>` element is a [deprecated HTML attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) (that happens to still function) and is NOT CSS. All CSS, whether [external, internal, or inline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) is banned from GitHub readmes and explicitly removed, as indicated through trial-and-error and in the two references above.

This leads me to split my answer into two answers here:

1. "Centering and aligning images in GitHub readmes using the deprecated HTML `align` attribute", and
2. "Centering and aligning images using modern CSS in any markdown document where you also have control over CSS styles".

Option 2 only works in places where you have full control over CSS styles, such as in a custom [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) website you make maybe?

---

## 1. Centering and aligning images *in GitHub readmes* using the deprecated HTML `align` attribute:

This works in any GitHub `*.md` markdown file, such as a GitHub `readme.md` file. It relies on the deprecated HTML `align` attribute, but still works fine. You can see a full demo of this in an actual GitHub readme in my eRCaGuy_hello_world repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md.

Notes:

1. *Be sure to set `width="100%"` inside each of your `<p>` paragraph elements below, or else the entire paragraph tries to allow word wrap around it, causing weird and less-predicable effects.*
2. To resize your image, simply set `width="30%"`, or whatever percent you'd like between 0% and 100%, to get the desired effect! This is *much* easier than trying to set a pixel size, such as `width="200" height="150"`, as using a `width` percent automatically adjusts to your viewer's screen and to the page display width, and it automatically resizes the image as you resize your browser window as well. It also avoids skewing the image into unnatural proportions. It's a great feature!
3. Options for the [(deprecated) HTML `align` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2) include `left`, `center`, `right`, and `justify`.

### 1.1. Align images left, right, or centered, with NO WORD WRAP:

This:

```html
**Align left:**
<p align="left" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>

**Align center:**
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>

**Align right:**
<p align="right" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>
```

Produces this:

[image]

If you'd like to set the text itself to left, center, or right, you can include the text inside the `<p>` element as well, as regular HTML, like this:

```html
<p align="right" width="100%">
    This text is also aligned to the right.<br>
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>
```

To produce this:

[image]

### 1.2. Align images left, right, or centered, WITH word wrap:

This:

```html
**Align left (works fine):**

<img align="left" width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">

[Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) (/ɑːrˈdwiːnoʊ/) is an open-source hardware and software company, project and user community that designs and manufactures single-board microcontrollers and microcontroller kits for building digital devices. Its hardware products are licensed under a [CC-BY-SA][4] license, while software is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) or the GNU General Public License (GPL),[1] permitting the manufacture of Arduino boards and software distribution by anyone. Arduino boards are available commercially from the official website or through authorized distributors. Arduino board designs use a variety of microprocessors and controllers. The boards are equipped with sets of digital and analog input/output (I/O) pins that may be interfaced to various expansion boards ('shields') or breadboards (for prototyping) and other circuits.


**Align center (doesn't really work):**

<img align="center" width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">

[Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) (/ɑːrˈdwiːnoʊ/) is an open-source hardware and software company, project and user community that designs and manufactures single-board microcontrollers and microcontroller kits for building digital devices. Its hardware products are licensed under a CC-BY-SA license, while software is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) or the GNU General Public License (GPL),[1] permitting the manufacture of Arduino boards and software distribution by anyone. Arduino boards are available commercially from the official website or through authorized distributors. Arduino board designs use a variety of microprocessors and controllers. The boards are equipped with sets of digital and analog input/output (I/O) pins that may be interfaced to various expansion boards ('shields') or breadboards (for prototyping) and other circuits.


**Align right (works fine):**

<img align="right" width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">

[Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) (/ɑːrˈdwiːnoʊ/) is an open-source hardware and software company, project and user community that designs and manufactures single-board microcontrollers and microcontroller kits for building digital devices. Its hardware products are licensed under a CC-BY-SA license, while software is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) or the GNU General Public License (GPL),[1] permitting the manufacture of Arduino boards and software distribution by anyone. Arduino boards are available commercially from the official website or through authorized distributors. Arduino board designs use a variety of microprocessors and controllers. The boards are equipped with sets of digital and analog input/output (I/O) pins that may be interfaced to various expansion boards ('shields') or breadboards (for prototyping) and other circuits.
```

Produces this:

[image]

### 1.3. Align images side-by-side:

*Reminder: MAKE SURE TO GIVE THE entire `<p>` paragraph element the full 100% column width (`width="100%"`, as shown below) or else text gets word-wrapped around it, botching your vertical alignment and vertical spacing/formatting you may be trying to maintain!*

This:

```html
33% width each (_possibly_ a little too wide to fit all 3 images side-by-side, depending on your markdown viewer):
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>

32% width each (perfect size to just barely fit all 3 images side-by-side):
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="32%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="32%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="32%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>

31% width each:
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="31%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="31%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="31%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>

30% width each:
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>
```

Produces this:

[image]

I am aligning all paragraph `<p>` elements above to the `center`, but you can also align `left` or `right`, as shown in previous examples, to force the row of images to get aligned that way too. Example:

This:

```html
Align the whole row of images to the right this time:
<p align="right" width="100%">
    <img width="25%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="25%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img width="25%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</p>
```

Produces this (aligning the whole row of images according to the `align` attribute set above, or to the *right* in this case). Generally, `center` is preferred, as done in the examples above.

[image]

### 1.4. Use a Markdown table to improve vertical spacing of odd-sized/odd-shaped images:

Sometimes, with odd-sized or different-shaped images, using just the "row of images" methods above produces slightly awkward-looking results.

This code produces two rows of images which have good horizontal spacing, but bad vertical spacing. This code:

```html
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta1.jpg">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta2.jpg">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta3.jpg">
</p>
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta4.jpg">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta5.jpg">
    <img width="32%" src="photos/pranksta6.jpg">
</p>
```

Produces this, since the last image in row 1 ("pranksta3.jpg") is a very tall image with 2x the height as the other images:

[image]

So, placing those two rows of images inside a markdown table forces nice-looking vertical spacing. Notice in the markdown table below that each image is set to have an HTML `width` attribute set to 100%. This is because it is *relative to the table cell the image sits in*, NOT relative to the page column width anymore. Since we want each image to fill the entire width of each cell, we set their widths all to `width="100%"`.

This markdown table with images in it:

```html
|                                               |                                               |                                               |
|-----------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta1.jpg"> | <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta2.jpg"> | <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta3.jpg"> |
| <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta4.jpg"> | <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta5.jpg"> | <img width="100%" src="photos/pranksta6.jpg"> |
```

Produces this, which looks much nicer and more well-spaced in my opinion, since vertical spacing is also centered for each row of images:

[image]

---

## 2. Centering and aligning images using modern CSS in any markdown document where you also have control over CSS styles:

This works in any markdown file, such as a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) website maybe?, where you do have full control over CSS styles. This does NOT work in any GitHub `*.md` markdown file, such as a `readme.md`, therefore, because GitHub expliclty scans for and disables all custom CSS styling you attempt to use. See above.

### TLDR;

Use this HTML/CSS to add and center an image and set its size to 60% of the screen space width inside your markdown file, which is usually a good starting value:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"
     style="display:block;float:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:60%">
```

Change the `width` CSS value to whatever percent you want, or remove it altogether to use the markdown default size, which I think is 100% of the screen width if the image is larger than the screen, or it is the actual image width otherwise.

Done!

Or, keep reading for a lot more information.

### Here are various HTML and CSS options which work perfectly inside markdown files, so long as CSS is not explicitly forbidden:

### 1. Center and configure (resize) ALL images in your markdown file:

Just copy and paste this to the top of your markdown file to center and resize all images in the file (then just insert any images you want with normal markdown syntax):

```html
<style>
img
{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60%;
}
</style>
```

Or, here is the same code as above but with detailed HTML and CSS comments to explain exactly what is going on:

```html
<!-- (This is an HTML comment). Copy and paste this entire HTML `<style>...</style>` element (block)
to the top of your markdown file -->
<style>
/* (This is a CSS comment). The below `img` style sets the default CSS styling for all images
hereafter in this markdown file. */
img
{
    /* Default display value is `inline-block`. Set it to `block` to prevent surrounding text from
    wrapping around the image. Instead, `block` format will force the text to be above or below the
    image, but never to the sides. */
    display:block;
    /* Common float options are `left`, `right`, and `none`. Set to `none` to override any previous
    settings which might have been `left` or `right`. `left` causes the image to be to the left,
    with text wrapped to the right of the image, and `right` causes the image to be to the right,
    with text wrapped to its left, so long as `display:inline-block` is also used. */
    float:none;
    /* Set both the left and right margins to `auto` to cause the image to be centered. */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    /* You may also set the size of the image, in percent of width of the screen on which the image
    is being viewed, for example. A good starting point is 60%. It will auto-scale and auto-size
    the image no matter what screen or device it is being viewed on, maintaining proporptions and
    not distorting it. */
    width:60%;
    /* You may optionally force a fixed size, or intentionally skew/distort an image by also
    setting the height. Values for `width` and `height` are commonly set in either percent (%)
    or pixels (px). Ex: `width:100%;` or `height:600px;`. */
    /* height:400px; */
}
</style>
```

Now, whether you insert an image using markdown:

```html
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png)
```

Or HTML in your markdown file:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
```

...it will be automatically centered and sized to 60% of the screenview width, as described in the comments within the HTML and CSS above. *(Of course the 60% size is really easily changeable too, and I present simple ways below to do it on an image-by-image basis as well).*

### 2. Center and configure images on a case-by-case basis, one at a time:

Whether or not you have copied and pasted the above `<style>` block into the top of your markdown file, this will also work, as it overrides and takes precedence over any file-scope style settings you may have set above:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png" style="display:block;float:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:60%">
```

You can also format it on multiple lines, like this, and it will still work:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"
     alt="this is an optional description of the image to help the blind and show up in case the
          image won't load"
     style="display:block; /* override the default display setting of `inline-block` */
            float:none; /* override any prior settings of `left` or `right` */
            /* set both the left and right margins to `auto` to center the image */
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width:60%; /* optionally resize the image to a screen percentage width if you want too */
            ">
```

### 3. In addition to all of the above, you can also create CSS style *classes* to help stylize individual images:

Add this whole thing to the top of your markdown file.

```html
<style>

/* By default, make all images center-aligned, and 60% of the width
of the screen in size */
img
{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60%;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to left-align, or "float left" */
.leftAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its right */
    margin-right:15px;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to right-align, or "float right" */
.rightAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its left */
    margin-left:15px;
}

</style>
```

Now, your `img` CSS block has set the default setting for images to be centered and 60% of the width of the screen space in size, but you can use the `leftAlign` and `rightAlign` CSS classes to override those settings on an image-by-image basis.

For example, this image will be **center-aligned and 60% in size** (the default I set above):

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
```

This image will be **left-aligned**, however, with text wrapping to its right, using the `leftAlign` CSS class we just created above!

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png" class="leftAlign">
```

It might look like this:

[image]

You can still **override any of its CSS properties via the `style` attribute**, however, such as width, like this:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png" class="leftAlign" style="width:20%">
```

And now you'll get this:

[image]

### 4. Create 3 CSS classes, but don't change the `img` markdown defaults

Another option to what we just showed above, where we modified the default `img` `property:value` settings and created 2 classes, is to just leave all the default markdown `img` properties alone, but create 3 custom CSS classes, like this:

```html
<style>

/* Create a CSS class to style images to center-align */
.centerAlign
{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    /* Set both the left and right margins to `auto` to cause the image to be centered. */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60%;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to left-align, or "float left" */
.leftAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its right */
    margin-right:15px;
    width:60%;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to right-align, or "float right" */
.rightAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its left */
    margin-left:15px;
    width:60%;
}

</style>
```

Use them, of course, like this:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png" class="centerAlign" style="width:20%">
```

Notice how I manually set the `width` property using the CSS `style` attribute above, but if I had something more complicated I wanted to do, I could also create some additional classes like this, adding them inside the `<style>...</style>` block above:

```html
/* custom CSS class to set a predefined "small" size for an image */
.small
{
    width:20%;
    /* set any other properties, as desired, inside this class too */
}
```

Now you can assign multiple classes to the same object, like this. Simply [separate class names by a space, NOT a comma](https://www.ironpaper.com/webintel/articles/assign-two-css-classes-together-for-one-object/). In the event of conflicting settings, I believe whichever setting comes *last* will be the one that takes effect, overriding any previously-set settings. This should also be the case in the event you set the same CSS properties multiple times in the same CSS class or inside the same HTML `style` attribute.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png" class="centerAlign small">
```

### 5. Consolidate Common Settings in CSS Classes:

The last trick is one I learned in this answer here: [How can I use CSS to style multiple images differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697549/how-can-i-use-css-to-style-multiple-images-differently/27701152#27701152). As you can see above, all 3 of the CSS `align` classes set the image width to 60%. Therefore, this common setting can be set all at once like this if you wish, then you can set the specific settings for each class afterwards:

```html
<style>

/* set common properties for multiple CSS classes all at once */
.centerAlign, .leftAlign, .rightAlign {
    width:60%;
}

/* Now set the specific properties for each class individually */

/* Create a CSS class to style images to center-align */
.centerAlign
{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    /* Set both the left and right margins to `auto` to cause the image to be centered. */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to left-align, or "float left" */
.leftAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its right */
    margin-right:15px;
}

/* Create a CSS class to style images to right-align, or "float right" */
.rightAlign
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    /* provide a 15 pixel gap between the image and the text to its left */
    margin-left:15px;
}

/* custom CSS class to set a predefined "small" size for an image */
.small
{
    width:20%;
    /* set any other properties, as desired, inside this class too */
}

</style>
```

---

## More Details:

### 1. My thoughts on HTML and CSS in Markdown

As far as I'm concerned, anything which can be written in a markdown document and get the desired result is all we are after, not some "pure markdown" syntax.

In C and C++, the compiler compiles down to assembly code, and the assembly is then assembled down to binary. Sometimes, however, you need the low-level control that only assembly can provide, and so you can write inline assembly right inside of a C or C++ source file. Assembly is the "lower level" language and it can be written right inside C and C++.

So it is with markdown. Markdown is the high-level language which is interpreted down to HTML and CSS. However, where we need extra control, we can just "inline" the lower-level HTML and CSS right inside of our markdown file, and it will still be interpreted correctly. In a sense, therefore, HTML and CSS *are* valid "markdown" syntax.

So, to center an image in markdown, use HTML and CSS.

### 2. Standard image insertion in markdown:

How to add a basic image in markdown with default "behind-the-scenes" HTML and CSS formatting:

This markdown:

```html
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png)
```

Will produce this output:

[image]

This is [my fire-shooting hexacopter I made](https://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2016/05/battlebots-season-2-buzz-fire-drone.html).

You can also optionally add a description in the opening square brackets. Honestly I'm not even sure what that does, but perhaps it gets converted into an [HTML `<img>` element `alt` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp), which gets displayed in case the image can't load, and may be read by screen readers for the blind. So, this markdown:

```html
![this is my hexacopter I built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png)
```

will also produce this output:

[image: this is my hexacopter I built]

### 3. More details on what's happening in the HTML/CSS when centering and resizing an image in markdown:

Centering the image in markdown requires that we use the extra control that HTML and CSS can give us directly. You can insert and center an individual image like this:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"
     alt="this is my hexacopter I built"
     style="display:block;
            float:none;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            ">
```

Here's more info. on what is going on here:

1. The `<img` part of the above code is the HTML "**start tag**", while the `>` at the end is the HTML "**end tag**".
2. Everything from the start tag to the end tag, inclusive, makes up this HTML `img` "**element**".
3. HTML `img` **"tags"/"elements"** are used to insert images into HTML.
4. Each of the assignments inside the element is configuring an HTML "**attribute**".
5. The **"style" attribute** accepts **CSS styling**, so everything inside the double quotes here: `style=""` is a CSS `property:value` key-value "**declaration**".

   1. Note that each CSS "property:value declaration" is separated by a semicolon (`;`), whereas each HTML "attribute" in this "element" is separated by a space ( ).
6. To get the image to center in our HTML and CSS code above, the key "attributes" are simply the `src` and `style` ones.
7. The `alt` one is optional.
8. Inside the HTML `style` attribute, which accepts CSS styling, the key declarations are all 4 that I show: `display:block`, `float:none`, `margin-left:auto`, and `margin-right:auto`.

   1. If nothing has previously set the `float` **property** before, then you can leave off this declaration, but it's a good idea to have it anyway just in case.
   2. If first learned how to center an image using HTML and CSS here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp.
9. CSS uses C-style comments (`/* my comment */`).

## References:

1. [GeeksForGeeks: HTML | `<p>` align Attribute](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-p-align-attribute/)
2. Read more about CSS Syntax here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp
3. Read about ["HTML Tags vs Elements" here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-elements.php).
4. I learned just about everything I know about HTML and CSS by clicking around on w3schools.com. Here's a few specific pages:

   1. %%%%%**https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp**
   2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

      1. https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float2
   3. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp
   4. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp
   5. HTML and CSS comments: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_comments.asp
5. My fire-shooting hexacopter I made: https://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2016/05/battlebots-season-2-buzz-fire-drone.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the longest answer I've seen on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Aligning text with an image on it's right does not work for gifs.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi, I disagree. I just did a full test. See this section and screenshot here: [Regular images (PNG, JPG, etc) vs GIFs](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/markdown#regular-images-png-jpg-etc-vs-gifs). GIFs work the exact same as PNG or JPG files. Compare [this file](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md) and [this file](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/gif_images.md) side-by-side to see for yourself.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi, do you have a syntax error preventing your gif from working correctly?

Comment: @GabrielStaples A week ago I tried all examples you show here, and they work. Every single one of them. Except when it's a gif, it refuses to to be aligned right to the text. But today after trying your right align example, all works! So I think it might be a change done on Github side or something, since they recently did make some changes. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: I will upvote this since I am sure it took a long time to write this answer :)

Answer (score 60):

Alternatively, if you have control of the CSS content, you could get clever with [URL parameters and CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/oknbt8r1/).

Markdown:

```
![A cute kitten](http://placekitten.com/200/300?style=centerme)
```

And CSS:

```
img[src$="centerme"] {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could create a variety of styling options this way and still keep the Markdown content clean of extra code. Of course, you have no control over what happens if someone else uses the Markdown somewhere else, but that’s a general styling issue with all Markdown documents one shares.

Comment: This works great, but using an anchor (#) over query string (?) is probably a better solution as I posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment/43691462#43691462 - however I don't believe the github readme.md supports defining css.

Comment: Perfect solution for those that run their own GitLab instance!

Answer (score 48):

For **left alignment**

```html
 <img align="left" width="600" height="200" src="https://www.python.org/python-.png">
```

For **right alignment**

```html
<img align="right" width="600" height="200" src="https://www.python.org/python-.png">
```

And for **center alignment**

```html
<p align="center">
  <img width="600" height="200" src="https://www.python.org/python-.png">
</p>
```

Fork it [here](https://gist.github.com/innat/49d12decb8f0c6cca2d994fba22886a2) for future references, if you find this useful.

Comment: Upvoted. However, all of your 3 examples have word-wrap of text around the images. I didn't like that, so after a ton of research and experimenting, I've got that fixed and added examples both with and without word-wrap, with left, center, and right alignment, as well as with multiple images in a single row. I then tested it all [in an actual github repo I made](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md). You can see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383408/4561887).

Answer (score 38):

It works for me on GitHub

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="...">
</p>
```

Answer (score 25):

We can use the following. Please change the `src` location of your image from the Git folder and add the alternate text if the image is not loaded:

```
 <p align="center">
    <img src="your image URL here" alt="alternate text">
 </p>
```

Comment: Re *"from the Git folder"*: Do you mean *"from the GitHub folder"*? In any case, can you elaborate on what you mean? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51992125/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This work well for repositories.

Answer (score 19):

My way to resolve the problem with image positioning was to use the HTML attributes:

```
![Image](Image.svg){ width="800" height="600" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto" }
```

The image was resized and centered properly, at least in my local Visual Studio Community Markdown renderer.

Then, I have pushed changes to repository and unfortunately realized that it is **not working for GitHub README.md file**. Nevertheless I will left this answer as it might help someone else.

So finally, I have ended up using good old HTML tag instead:

```
<img src="Image.svg" alt="Image" width="800" height="600" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto" />
```

But guess what? Some JavaScript method replaced my `style` attribute! I have even tried `class` attribute and with the same result!

Then I have found following [gist page](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/7d2e0e1bc78f4ac59a123ddf8b74932d) where even more old-school HTML was used:

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="Image.svg" alt="Image" width="800" height="600" />
</p>
```

This one is working fine however, and I would like to leave it without further comments...

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Do you mean *[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)*? If so, please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51800546/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen actually I forgot that this investigation was done during my C# project which was implemented through **Visual Studio Community** edition. I have changed it to proper name of the editor.

Answer (score 10):

You can also resize the image to the desired **width** and **height**. For example:

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://anyserver.com/image.png" width="750px" height="300px"/></p>
```

To add a centered **caption** to the image, just one more line:

```
<p align="center">This is a centered caption for the image<p align="center">
```

Fortunately, this works both for README.md and the GitHub Wiki pages.

Answer (score 8):

Just go to the <kbd>Readme.md</kbd> file and use this code.

```
<div align="center">
<img src=https://newfastuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/bW7QXVB.png" >
<p>Perfectly balanced</p>
</div>
```

---

[image]

---

`<div align=”center”> [ Your content here ]</div>` fits everything in the page and center aligns it according to the dimensions of the page.

Comment: Only using div container was doing it right on GitLab ReadME page

Comment: Small correction: s/b `src="https://newfastuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/bW7QXVB.png"`.  Otherwise, works a treat.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the answer a little bit to support local images, just **replace** `FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER` with your image path and check it out.

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER">
</p>
```

Comment: Which answer? There were five non-deleted answers when this answer was posted. Or do you mean *"the answers"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47998157/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

A "pure" Markdown approach that can handle this is adding the image to a table and then centering the cell:

```markdown
| ![Image](img.png) |
| :--: |
```

It should produce HTML similar to this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;"><img src="img.png" alt="Image"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work: the table's width is determined by the width of its contents. It also puts a border around the image (per github's default style sheet).

Comment: I didn't realize it did that. Outside of GitHub this is how I center images in markdown.

Comment: Upvoted, because your answer here helped contribute to my section **1.4. Use a markdown table to improve vertical spacing of odd-sized/odd-shaped images**, which I just added [to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383408/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

## Table Approach

Another approach is using a table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="center">
      <span style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> Some Text </span>
    </td>
    <td valign="center">
      <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=hossein13m&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Keep in mind** that this will work on the GitHub readme files but not on the code snippets here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Github that avoids the use of the deprecated `align` attribute. It also avoids needing to fill with &nbsp. I made a transparent 1920x5 `line.png` with width="100%" and made that the last row of every column. This spaces each column equally.

```
||
|:--:|
| <img width=200px src="image.png" alt="image alt text"> |
| <img width="100%" src="line.png"> |
```

Answer (score 0):

### Correct way to make any imaging center.

You can just wrap your image inside a `p` tag, that's it.

> Here is an example, of how you can make your image in center

```markdown
<p align="center" width="100%">
  <img src="./icon/icon128.png" alt="word counter pro logo" />
</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

If **modifying the image** is not a problem for you, and

if **you know the approximate width of the container** that will display your markdown, and

if **your image is used in one place only** (for example a README used only in GitHub),

then you can edit your image in an image editor and pad it equally on both sides.

Before padding:

[image: Image before edit]

After padding:

[image: Image after edit]

Original image (width = 250px):

[image: Original image]

Padded image (width = 660px):

[image: Padded image]

Answer (score -4):

I don't know why no one mentioned about the `<center>` tag. refer [doc](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks) for more reading. This solution is deprecated.

```
<center>
    <h1>Hola App</h1> 
    <img src="root/static/assets/img/beer.svg">
</center>
```

Comment: Because it has been deprecated for decades already?

Answer (score -19):

This is quite simple really.

```
-> This is centered Text <-
```

So keeping that in mind, you can apply this to the img syntax.

```
->![alt text](/link/to/img)<-
```

Comment: What flavor of Markdown is that?

Comment: I'm curious here, as well. That *looks* like a screenshot of GitHub, but Redcarpet definitely does not implement that. How did you do this? Can you link to the file on GitHub?

Comment: It's a Jeckyll site, so GitHub parses to code before it even gets in the repo.

Comment: Just FYI for everyone who is considering flagging this for moderator attention: the fact that an answer doesn't work for you is not a reason to flag it. Just comment and/or downvote. I'm not going to delete an answer for technical inaccuracies. If vdclouis wants to delete it himself because the community finds it to be unhelpful, that should be his choice.

Comment: I just tried this on Github in a readme.md file and confirmed it didn't seem to work. I'd be interested in the OP showing a demo and screenshot of it, however, in whatever context he got it to work.

Comment: Perhaps respond to the comments?