# How can I use CSS to style multiple images differently?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, inline-styles

I am basically styling a long essay with various images scattered throughout. 
I would like the first image to "float: left" and the second one to "float: right". I know that I can style the images like this:

```
img {
float: left;
}
```

This makes each image have the same style. How do I style each image differently? I tried to put each image in a different div class, so that I could style them differently, but it didn't work.

I also understand, that I could style each image in the html  tag, like this:

```
<img src="ABCD.png" alt="Raoul Hausmann's ABCD" align="left" height="300px">
```

I keep hearing that it is best to keep style in the external style sheet (CSS), separate from the html. Is this a case where inline styling is necessary?

Comment: Seems like you were on the right track--what "didn't work" about putting classes on the divs containing the images? Can you show us what you did and what happened? BTW, specifying height using the `height` attribute on the `img` tag is no longer the preferred way to do this; use the `height` CSS attribute instead. Same with `align`.

Comment: @torazaburo I was putting the "class=__" in the wrong place, but all the answers here cleared it up for me. Thanks for confirming the info about the height attribute in the html tag, I had a feeling it wasn't right.

Answer (score 8):

You can give each image a class or id that will help you to define different css for each image like

```
<img src="" class="image1">
<img src="" class="image2">
```

in css file you can define

```
.image1
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
.image2
{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your image a class and then you can style all images with that class like this:

```css
.left {
  border: solid 5px red;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  border: solid 5px blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="ABCD.png" class="left">
<img src="ABCD.png" class="right">
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above are fine, I would only suggest grouping the common settings of picture in this case so that the left/right classes only contains that what is different.

```
/* Group the common attributesso that you only need to set it once */
.picture, .leftPicture, .rightPicture {
    border: 2px dotted gray;
    width: 200px;
}

.leftPicture {
    float:left;
}

.rightPicture {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: How do I group them in the html tag? I know how to put one class like this: <img src="ABCD.png" alt="Raoul Hausmann's ABCD" class="leftPicture"> I don't know how to incorporate the ".Picture" class in the html.

Comment: You can use only .leftPicture, I included .picture as an example for normal images that does not require aligning. HTML ..class="leftPicture".. I did the grouping in CSS. You can do it in HTML (remove the references to leftPicture & rightPicture next to .picture and then assign two classes in CSS ..class="image leftPicture".. to the same affect.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
img{width: 200px;height:200px;background-color: antiquewhite}
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}


    <img src="ABCD.png" alt="Raoul Hausmann's ABCD" class="left">
    <img src="ABCD.png" alt="Raoul Hausmann's ABCD" class="right">
```

*this will float two images one in left and another in right*

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
   var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
   var modalImg = document.getElementById('modal-image');

   window.openModal = function(img) {
   modal.style.display = "block";
   modalImg.src = img.getAttribute("data-highres");
   }

   

   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
   }

   window.onclick = function() {
   if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
```

```css
#myImg {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  #myImg:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }

  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #bbbbbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<img onclick="openModal(this);" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/LqKAyU-o6M4" data-highres="https://unsplash.com/photos/LqKAyU-o6M4">


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <!-- Close button -->
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <!-- Modal content -->
   <img class="modal-content" id="modal-image">
</div>
```