# Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo

Tags: css, github, markdown

I am having trouble verifying the name of the `.css` file that will modifying the `readme.md` file at the root of Github repo.

I believe it is:

```
.github/github.css
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything to the Markdown. Does anyone know if this is incorrect?

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible? GitHub doesn't provide any mechanism to use your own CSS file.

Comment: I have seen github.css files in projects, which I believe are designed to modify the markdown of the project. Github itself is responsible for loading the CSS before rendering the markdown. Certainly possible.

Comment: "Github itself is responsible for loading the CSS before rendering the markdown. Certainly possible." Can you provide an example? Or relevant documentation? I've been using GitHub for almost a decade and I've never seen this. I'm pretty confident that there is no mechanism for providing your own CSS file for README rendering.

Comment: Can you point me to a good answer that I have not accepted? there was one regarding deleting git branches but I didn't accept an answer b/c I didn't personally try either of the answers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

GitHub does not allow for CSS to affect `README.md` files through CSS for security reasons (as if you could inject CSS into a ReadMe, you could easily launch a phishing attack). This includes both stylesheets referenced through `<link rel>` and inline styles used with `<style>`.

The readmes are in markdown syntax, so **some** styling can be done, such as adding colours through placeholder images, just like here on StackOverflow. For example, you can add red squares [image: #f03c15] with the following:

```
- ![#f03c15](https://placehold.it/15/f03c15/000000?text=+) `#f03c15`
```

You can also make use of things like `diff`, `json`, `html`, `js` and `css` to affect text colouring.

Comment: Is there official documentation on this? Particularly to what degree, if any, inline css is supported in github-rendered README.md files.

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @SamTuke this is documented in the [github/Markup](https://github.com/github/markup) project (specifically step 2). They used to link to the code, but they are apparently using something different now, which is not public.  As per [#1246](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1246) the list of allowed elements and attributes is [here](https://gist.github.com/kivikakk/622b5dcf395e26c49e2334f0eb19e6f9). Specifically, style tags are not on the whitelist at all. They are never allowed and will always be stripped out.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. [I'm able to specify styles!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383408/4561887) I just don't know how to reference a style sheet instead of including it inline is all.... That's what I need help to figure out. I'm no CSS/HTML expert.

Comment: I may be mistaken. Trying to figure this out now. My Markdown viewer in my browser allows me to do CSS style stuff, but Github does indeed seem to be rejecting it once I push a change to GitHub. :(

Comment: Yeah this sucks. CSS seems to be explicitly removed and not rendered by Github. See: https://github.community/t/github-flavored-markdown-doesnt-render-css-styles-inside-a-html-block/126258/2?u=electricrcaircraftguy.

Comment: If you see my answer below, there's a kind of "hacky" way to get CSS to be rendered by embedding HTML in a [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element

Answer (score 59):

You can add some HTML (actually XHTML) and CSS inside a [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) tag inside of an svg file and then embed that inside of an `<img>` tag in your GitHub README.

This is a simple animation in CSS that changes the color of the h1 text:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  animation: myanimation 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
  from {
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

You can embed the style and HTML into a `<foreignObject>` tag inside of an svg like so:

**example.svg**

```xml
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <style>
            h1 {
                color: red;
                animation: mymove 2s infinite;
            }

            @keyframes mymove {
                from {
                    color: red;
                }
                to {
                    color: yellow;
                }
            }
            </style>
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Then, lastly you can embed the svg in your README, using an `<img>` tag and it should render your HTML with the applied CSS styles:

**README.md**

```
# My GitHub README

Welcome to my README!

<div align="center">
    <img src="example.svg" width="400" height="400" alt="css-in-readme">
</div>
```

[another example & source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/css-in-readme-like-wat)

Comment: How about security issues?

Comment: Apparently, image animations of this kind only run during window resizing! At least that's cool :)

Answer (score 1):

For simple and even complex Styling for `Readme.md` file. You can also use SVG in this simplest way, among other ways.

This is my Readme.md with an example to style.
Readme.md:

```
# Using CSS in Readme.md file

Readme.md files do not allow direct CSS classes injection.

Though, there are several ways you can inject a CSS file or link into your README.md file, I prefer using the SVG files for simple styling or even complex charts and tables. [see my simple `Readme.md` example with SVG styling][1]

## ![plot](./title.svg)

This is a title that can be manipulated.

## ![plot](./subTitle.svg)

This is a sub-title with cyan color but can be manipulated
```

title.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="80">
    <style src="./style.css" >
        .title {
          transition: fill .3s ease;
          <!-- cursor: works in github not in preview mode -->
          cursor: pointer;
          font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
          border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
          fill:#2c1300;
          text-anchor: middle;
          dominant-baseline: middle;
          font-size: 24px;
        }

    </style>

    <g class="title">
        <rect rx="5" width="100%" height="80"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" width="" font-weight="bold" fill="yellow" >TypeScript Course</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

subTitle.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40">
    <style src="./style.css" >
        .subTitle {
            fill: #00FFFF;
            transition: fill .3s ease;
        }
    </style>

 <g class="subTitle">
        <text x="30%" y="10" dy=".35em">
            TypeScript Jobs
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -4):

Wrap the images in a tag as shown below

```
<div>
<img  src="/images/count.png" width="250" >  &nbsp; 
<img  src="/images/home.png" width="250">  &nbsp;
<img  src="/images/profile.png" width="250">  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Note: **the images folder and the readme are in the root directory of the project**