# FontAwesome on GitHub flavored markdown

Tags: github, font-awesome, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I want to know the best way to represent FontAwesome icons on GitHub flavoured markdown. Currently What I do is I include the path for my compiler to find FontAwesome and Academ-icons.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jpswalsh/academicons/master/css/academicons.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then write my desired Academicon as

```
<i class="ai ai-arxiv ai-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-medium fa-5x" aria-hidden="true">
```

Mind you this is a markdown file that I am editing. When viewing on `MarkdownPad`, my README renders with the icons, but when pushed to Git the icons don't show. Compiling with `Pandoc` to an HTML page still renders the icons. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a few months of initially posing this question, I found the answer. So apparently GitHub does not support CSS rendering for security purposes. [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956450/7517511) to this question.

I have verified this using custom CSS and trying to centrally render a logo on my README but it doesn't work either. [Here is the README](https://github.com/arnabsanyal/Applied-Natural-Language-Processing-CSCI544-20201/blob/master/README.md) in question

I am not exactly sure but READMEs on GitLab may still render custom CSS. I have used GitLab but the GitLab settings vary w.r.t. the org.