# Image Flexbox Styling Not Working in Github Markdown

Tags: css, github, flexbox, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I wanted to make my github markdown responsive when viewed on different screens
so, I added css flexbox to the images.
It works fine when I try md preview in VS Code,
but after I push all changes on github, then the styling are not working properly

Does the style tag works as normally other html tags works?

**Or Is there any other good way to present screenshots in readme file, Like showing small tiles in readme and expanding them when clicked.    Some help will be appreciated**

code repo: https://github.com/sachuverma/React-E-Commerce-v2
styles code:

```
.row-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-main {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column{
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column-main {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .column{
    flex: 100%;
  }
}

img{
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

img:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**vs code preview**
[image: vsc preview]

**github preview**
[image: github preview]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo)

Comment: @Chris yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `width: 100%` instead of `flex:100%`for the flex items in the media queries

Comment: that also didn't worked. Its like no css is applied because I also tried adding hover effect on images, but that too wasn't working. Can't we add css to markdowns?
Like we can add html tags, but style tag isn't working.