# Markdown - Table with invisible vertical lines

Tags: arrays, markdown

How can I write a markdown table in which the vertical lines are invisible?

I just started using markdown and I was surprised not to find the answer easily.

My markdown file is displayed on github so I don't know if I can use markdown packages/libraries.

Comment: [Markdown is about _content_, not presentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html): "HTML is a _publishing_ format; Markdown is a _writing_ format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text." To change its appearance when rendered as HTML you need to provide or modify its CSS, and GitHub doesn't let you do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo)

Comment: @Chris Yes thanks!