# Custom styling isn't working in .md files

Tags: markdown

I'm using markdown in my next.js project:

- I have multiple .md files
- I've installed: remark, remark-HTML, and gray-matter

Now, I'd like to change the font size of the paragraph/ p-tag. I've seen other StackOverflow posts saying that inline-CSS should work in the .md files, but it doesn't in my case. I've tried something like this:

```
<p style="font-size: 14px">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

and

```
<font size="3"> This is my text number 3</font>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working?" Is the raw HTML not included in the output, Is the style attribute being ignored or missing from the output? Or something else?

Comment: When I add the inline styling the entire paragraph isn't shown. Maybe it's because the content is shown in a component where I'm using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?! But how can I still change the style?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer [here](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#html): "For security reasons, not all Markdown applications support HTML in Markdown documents."

So what I did: Style the content (from .md-file), which is wrapped in a component, by adding styling rules to the component itself, not the .md-file.