# How can I add this css in readme.md?

Tags: html, css, readme

How I can use this effect in a readme.md file ?

```
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
```

```
h1 {
    background-image: url(./image.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Here is what Im getting when I write directly html and css in readme
[readme screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV5fm.png)

Comment: Markdown supports HTML, so you can write HTML with inline CSS in your .md file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply but it is not working can you take a look at my main post ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

Answer (score 1):

You simply enclose the css with   tags.

Should render correctly with the majority of markdown parsers.

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<style>
h1 {
    background-image: url(./image.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

On GitHub.com this trick sadly does not work. This is due to their sanitization process. "The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and class or id attributes."

Read more at:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22728

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956450/16512927

Comment: Hey, just tried but its not working. I edited my main post to show you what Im getting with github

Comment: Ohh... this is a Readme.md on GitHub. Sorry, It's to my understanding that css is blacklisted for security reasons. See this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956450/16512927