# How to remove line after H1 or # in GitHub README

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

This annoying line after the H1 just messed up the design of my README, is there a way to remove it?

My code right now is just this, i tried to search in Stack and other foruns, but sadly no good answers.

```
<h1 align="center"> <p> Hello World! </p> </h1>
<h1 align="center"> Eu sou Enzo Bustos </h1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom css file for readme.md in a Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo)

Comment: Remove the `p` from inside the `<h1>`...

Answer (score -1):

Probably custom CSS would solve it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956361/custom-css-file-for-readme-md-in-a-github-repo) you can figure out how to add it. It still works, I've just checked it. Example how to do it:

**header.svg**

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <style>
            h1 {
                border:none;
            }
            </style>
            <h1>header</h1>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

**readme.md**

```html
<img src="header.svg" width="400" height="400" />
```

Comment: well yes, but the text in the `img` will not be selectable/searchable etc. So why even go through the trouble of using an `h1` inside the svg..?

I think the real answer is that what OP wants is not possible in GitHub READMEs.