# Center .gif in Github Readme horizontally

Tags: github, markdown, gif

I'm trying to center gif, here is the markdown code:

```
![Demo](demo.gif)
```

The code above align my gif in the left (See below image):

[image]

So, I tried to put the markdown inside `<p>` tag like this but it does not work:

```
<p align="center">
![Demo](demo.gif)
</p>
```

My question: I want to center .gif in Github README horizontally, is there a way to do it?
Example of what I want:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I center an image in the README.md file on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/how-do-i-center-an-image-in-the-readme-md-file-on-github)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of using markdown, I used `<img>` tag. Here is my code:

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="demo.gif" alt="animated" />
</p>
```