# Center video in GitHub readme

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

How to center GitHub readme video horizontally?

I tried:

```
<p align="center">
  <video src="myvideo.mp4" width=400/>
<p/>
```

It works when `p` is containing `img` ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342526/center-gif-in-github-readme-horizontally)) but not with `video` tag in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem recently try div instead of p tag

```
<div align="center">
  <video src="myvideo.mp4" width="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: the ending of the div ...