# centered emoji's in github readme

Tags: html, css, github, emoji, readme

I have following emoji which converts into stars emoji when used in markdown and i want them to align centered in readme file.

```
:star::star::star:
```

I have used

```
<p align = "center"> :star::star::star: </p>
```

but this is not working.

Comment: I recommend tagging markdown, as it is GitHub's readme language

Comment: @IanSwift Could you explain more that what i should write there?

Comment: [Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/github-readme-md-center-image)

Comment: @AbishekKumar Not working on github. Does anyone have a solution for github readme files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, just wrap with `center` tag

```
<center><p align = "center"> :star::star::star: </p> </center>
```