# How to have a row of images centered, aligned left, or aligned right in CSS

Tags: html, css

If I do this in HTML (which [works perfectly inside GitHub markdown readmes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/github-readme-md-center-image/62383408#62383408) by the way):

```html
30% width each:
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
    <img width="30%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>
```

I get this: a nicely-centered row of images. See [my demo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md#13-align-images-side-by-side).
[image]

This is exactly what I want. The problem is, the `align` HTML attribute is deprecated entirely in HTML5, and therefore shouldn't be used, and the `width` attribute is deprecated in HTML5 for most tags, including the `p` tag, and so it also shouldn't be used. So, in my GitHub Pages Jekyll site I'm trying to use CSS instead, so I don't rely on deprecated HTML attributes.

**I can't figure out how to do this in CSS, however. How can I do this in CSS? Note that I'd like to be able to align this row of images, left, right, or center**, just as can be done by setting `align="left"`, `align="right"`, or `align="center"` in the deprecated HTML element above.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it creates a row of images which remains aligned left:

```html
<style>
/* align center withOUT word wrap--the element goes on its own line */
.alignCenterNoWrap
{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  /* Set both the left and right margins to `auto` to cause the image to be centered. */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}
</style>

<div class="alignCenterNoWrap" style="width:100%;">
    <img style="width:30%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img style="width:30%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
    <img style="width:30%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png">
</div>
```

Other CSS classes I've been working on to try to get the alignment I seek:

```html
/* align left WITH word wrap to the right of the element */
.alignLeftWrap
{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  /* provide a gap between the element and the text to its right */
  margin-right: 15px;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}

/* align right WITH word wrap to the left of the element */
.alignRightWrap
{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  /* provide a gap between the element and the text to its left */
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}


/* align left withOUT word wrap--the element goes on its own line */
.alignLeftNoWrap
{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}

/* align center withOUT word wrap--the element goes on its own line */
.alignCenterNoWrap
{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  /* Set both the left and right margins to `auto` to cause the image to be centered. */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}

/* align right withOUT word wrap--the element goes on its own line */
.alignRightNoWrap
{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0px;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}


/* Force this element to NOT wrap around any floating elements above it which have word wrap.
Therefore, this element will begin on a new line, even if it would otherwise try to wrap
around the above element instead. */
.noWrapAroundAbove
{
  clear: both;
}
```

### References:

1. [my repo] https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md
2. [my answer] [GitHub README.md center image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090472/github-readme-md-center-image/62383408#62383408)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **display: flex** on parent div and align content inside it with **justify-content** property, that works in conjunction with *display: flex*. Here is an example, if I caught right your idea. Just try to apply different values to *justify-content* property: https://jsbin.com/quduwavene/1/edit?html,css,output

CSS:

```
.alignCenterNoWrap
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.alignCenterNoWrap a {
  dislay: block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.alignCenterNoWrap img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put `display:flex;` and `justify-content: space-around`, or `justify-content:space-between` as well as `align-items:center` in CSS on the alignCenterNoWrap.