# How to underline a header in jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am trying to underline the following header in jupyter notebooks:

### Definitions

I don't want the underline to span the entire screen.

I want the final result to be something like this

Definitions (h2)

---

The Internet: Global Network of interconnected computers that communicate via TCP/IP

How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

HTML underline:
## Definitions

3+ underscores

### Definitions

---

3+ dashes

### Definitions

---

All of these result in the horizontal line spanning the entire screen

Comment: The "___" and "---" resulted in a faulty rendering. I want to have 

Definitions
------------

Where the underline only spans the length of the header

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer to 'Get underlined text with Markdown' here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47354053/8508004):

```
## <ins>Definitions</ins>


The Internet: Global Network of interconnected computers that communicate via TCP/IP
```

Results in:

[image]